# How to pass url to ajax success?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

This my template fragment for comments/

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    <div class="comment-wrapper">
        <a href="{% url 'comment:update_comment' slug=product.slug id=comment.id %}" class="comment-edit-img">
            <img src="{% static 'media/work_images/icons-edit.png' %}"  alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="{% url 'comment:delete_comment' comment.pk %}" class="comment-del-img">
            <img src="{% static 'media/work_images/icons-delete.png' %}"  alt="">
        </a>
        <p class="comment-text">{{comment.comment_text}}</p>
        {% if comment.update_date != comment.posted_date %}
            <span class="comment-author">
                {% trans 'Posted' %}:
                {{comment.author}}
            </span>
            <span class="comment-date">
                {% blocktrans trimmed with update=comment.update_date %}
                    {{update}}
                {% endblocktrans %}
            </span>
        {% else %}
            <span class="comment-author">
                {% trans 'Updated by' %}:
                {{comment.author}}
            </span>
            <span class="comment-date">
                {% blocktrans trimmed with posted=comment.posted_date %}
                    {{posted}}
                {% endblocktrans %}
            </span>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}enter code here
```

My ajax code /

```
$('#add-comment').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#add-comment-form');
    $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize()).done(function(data) {
        $('#comment-box').prepend(
            "<div class='comment-wrapper'>"+
            "<a href='???' class='comment-edit-img'>up</a>"+
            "<a href='???' class='comment-del-img'>x</a>"+
            "<p class='comment-text'>"+data.text+"</p>"+
            "<span class='comment-author'>"+data.author+"</span>"+
            "<span class='comment-date'>"+data.date+"</span>"+
            "</div>"
        );
    })
});
```

How can I pass the url of the address for tag `<a>` the same as in the template? Or maybe there is a more correct solution to ajax?

Comment: Please try to keep titles useful and succinct, and free of chatty please-halp-me material as much as possible. It may be worth browsing the front page to see how titles are generally written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common practice is to assign the urls to JS variables in your template file and use them in the JS file.

```
<script>
var URLS = {
  addItem:        '{% url "cart:cart-add" %}',
  removeItem:     '{% url "cart:cart-remove" %}',
}
</script>
```

And then using them `URLS.addItem`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I pass a variable to the tag itself, so that the link works?

Comment: String concatation. Like you are you are doing with `data.text`. `"<a href='"+URLS.url+"' class='comment-edit-img'>up</a>"`

Comment: Thanks, already understood, but with variables it did not turn out, passed from view as data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Task is solved. Here is the code, suddenly someone will help:

```
$('#add-comment').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#add-comment-form');
    $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize()).done(function(data) {
        $('#comment-box').append(
            "<div class='comment-wrapper'>"+
            "<a class='comment-edit-img'"+"href='"+data.update_url+"'>"+"<img src='/static/media/work_images/icons-edit.png'>"+"</a>"+
            "<a href='#' id="+data.id+" class='comment-del-img' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#category-del-modal'>"+
            "<img src='/static/media/work_images/icons-delete.png'>"+
            "</a>"+
            "<p class='comment-text'>"+data.text+"</p>"+
            "<span class='comment-author'>"+data.author+"</span>"+
            "<span class='comment-date'>"+data.date+"</span>"+
            "</div>"
        );
    })
});
```